# Bootstrap Carousel failing

Tags: javascript, html

I've been having trouble implementing Material Design Bootstrap's carousel. I copy and pasted the carousel example from their website, and I've made sure to have both the JS and CSS in the correct order when loaded. Currently my page only renders the image and text, and can be clicked on with a light effect, but no other images or slides appear and it never switches between them. It also creates a large whitespace on my screen after the carousel.

edit: Changed script.php to script.js

edit 2: Updated index.php that still doesn't work completely:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <title>Site Name</title>
    <?php //include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/head.php'; ?>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site/css/style.css">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://site/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/nav.php'; ?>
    </header>

    <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
    <div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <!--Indicators-->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!--/.Indicators-->
        <!--Slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="view">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
                    <p>First text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <!--Mask color-->
                <div class="view">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg" alt="Second slide">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-strong"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
                    <p>Secondary text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <!--Mask color-->
                <div class="view">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg" alt="Third slide">
                    <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
                    <p>Third text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Slides-->
        <!--Controls-->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        <!--/.Controls-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->       
    <div class='shell'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <p class='content content-header' >Title</p>
            <p class='content content-text' >Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    <?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/footer.php'; ?>
</footer>
```

edit 3: Pictures of before and after: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p15kI.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL6GT.png)

I blocked sensitive information. All my other pages work fine and there is no issue with CSS. It is just this carousel that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Changing that, both on my server and in the file, doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v4f6g2v4/5/ I made this jsfiddle and it seems to be working how it should be..

Comment: The fiddle works for me online, but when I copied and added it to my own site it still doesn't work. Is this an error within my code? Or is something else possible messed up?

Comment: no. I think your problem is the way you are including your scripts. Take a look at my answer and it should help..

Comment: It looks now like your custom css isn’t loading properly. What I would recommend is to comment out every script file and css file you have in your head and uncommonent them one by one. Sometimes it can depend on the order or if there is a rule being overridden in your bootstrap css which also exists in your custom css for instance. This will cause issues. That is my suggestion to try.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it'll take me a while to figure this out. I might just look for an alternative solution. I might just start with a fresh page and add it in step by step.

Comment: That's always a good idea..You could also just use bootstrap's carousel if you wanted. It could be easier than including all those other libraries.. 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp .. Also. I generally tend not to use php or any back end code unless I absolutely need to (ie talking to a SQL database). It looks like for what you're trying to do... You should just use HTML, CSS and javascript. But that's just my advice. I try to make things as simple as they can be. Good luck and if my answer helped, make sure to give it an upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your index.php page in the head tag. Try adding all of your scripts there.For now just start with the CDN from their website.. Try replacing your  tags with this.. Generally it's good to reference all the script and css files you are going to use inside the  tags.

```
<head>         
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.13.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.0/js/mdb.min.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site/css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://site/js/app.js"></script> 
</head>
```

Comment: Doing this makes the carousel work...but then breaks the rest of my site/page. Is it possible I am working with an outdated version of bootstrap? The carousel also only works when I include all of this, not just the scripts, so I believe the problem is isolated to the CSS.

Comment: you also need to include the rest of your custom scripts and css in the head tag. Also. Remove this line "  <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/scripts.js';?>" from your index.php file. See my edit of what should go inside the head.

Comment: I've edited my question with the current file. Right now the footer, which previously stayed at the button is now taking up most of the screen, the carousel is working, my nav bar section is broken and no longer working. I'll post two pictures quickly to show you.